# Lint warning for invoking an async function without `.then()` or `await` without TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, eslint

In TypeScript, it is possible to check and warn the developer if they are calling an `async` function synchronously.

For those that want less overhead and using node.js v9.0+, is it possible to have any linter give us a warning if we have something like this?

```
async function foo() {
  return;
}

var result = foo(); // warning right here because there is no await
```

The reason being is that it is not apparently if a function is returning a promise/is await unless we explicitly name it `fooAsync`, look into the implementation, or assume everything is async. Or maybe devs messed up and forgot to write `await`.

Just want a warning to catch errors at dev time and not runtime.

Comment: Not sure why you'd *want* this, when there's plenty of use cases for Promises...

Comment: Maybe I'm not writing my question correctly. Are you saying don't use async/await and use the Promise pattern?

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-sync

Comment: `async/await` is just sugar. `async` functions automatically return Promises which may be used without `await`ing them if desired. Why would you limit your flexibility?

Comment: @JaredSmith I think the point is that `tslint` can warn when promises aren't being handled correctly, and the op is looking for something that can warn him when using node.js with javascript (instead of node.js with typescript).

Comment: @ps2goat I understand *what* the OP wants, what I don't understand is *why*, although plenty of people seem to also want it, so...

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? @JaredSmith The idea is that if you have async functions that you are calling without `await`, you cannot be guaranteed their execution order. For example, what if you have a process that is `validatePassword(); sendMoney()`, but `validatePassword()` is async and you forgot the `await`? Then the second function may be called before the first one throws.

Comment: @slhck you make sendMoney take a parameter of a validated password object, and since this is Typescript you have validatePassword return a discriminated union that sendMoney's signature only accepts one member of so that the type system enforces runtime checking at the call site at compile time. I realize that you probably only meant that as a motivating example but still. I can't see any real use case for this: sometimes the caller will want to cache the Promise and sometimes they will want to await it and it seems really weird to me that you'd try to *force* the caller's hand.

Comment: @JaredSmith Sure, the example was a bit contrived. I guess you could argue that `validatePassword()` should have never been made async to begin with. But most of the time I have to use async functions, the order in which they are called matters a lot, and I've run across a lot of unexpected runtime behavior by simply forgetting the `await`, when it was not the intent of the developer to have the function run asynchronously. Maybe a better check would be for function calls that neither use `await` nor `.then()`.

Comment: @slhck then I would say this is properly a job for the linter as it is a code smell (something *likely* but not *necessarily* wrong) rather than the type system where a caller could legitimately want to cache a promise, or call an async function purely for a side-effect and then not have their program compile. Still on the caller though, I'm not sure that you as the *author of the async function* can or should enforce this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that is not possible. As you say, it requires type inference or at least annotations to decide whether a function will return a promise. That's what a typechecker like the TypeScript compiler does, not a linter.

Comment: But does this exist for TypeScript then? If so, where (e.g. in eslint)?

Comment: @slhck typescript-eslint does have [*no-floating-promises*](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-floating-promises.md) and [*await-thenable*](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/await-thenable.md) rules

Comment: `no-floating-promises` does the trick. Would you like to amend your answer with that?