# Check if a js function is called using await?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have a `checkPermission` function in which I pull session, reach database and confirm permission. If the action is not permitted, the function throws.

```
await checkPermission("USER_READ"); // This will throw if not permitted.
// Do permission specific stuff.
```

Problem is if I forget await, it will not wait and move to unpermitted code. Can I programatically check in `checkPermission` function if `await` is used so I can throw if `await` is not used? Or is there any other way I can enforce `await` for a given function and throw if not used.

**Note:** I know I can put it in an if and check if it returns `Promise`. But that is not what I am asking.

Comment: Use a linter. There's no way to "enforce" awaiting a promise, that's simply not supported by the way they're designed.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43416214/how-do-i-check-if-a-javascript-function-returns-a-promise

Comment: I know this won't answer your questoion but: Wouldnt it be better to have a 'default deny'  permissions checking rather than relying on thrown errors? It's always better to give less permissions rather than too many in my opinion.

Comment: no, forgot `await` is like forgot the whole check, all you can do is remember to do it.

Comment: Alternatively you can return an object contains the restricted api, so you **need** to wait the object to continue.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50047487/lint-warning-for-invoking-an-async-function-without-then-or-await-without

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily accomplish this by using eslint and add it as part of your CI pipeline

> Disallow async functions which have no await expression
> (require-await)

```
   eslint require-await: "error"
```

https://eslint.org/docs/rules/require-await

Comment: This disallows async functions with no await IN them, but still allows an async function that is not await'ed

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this is to use a linter, if for some reason you can't, you can perform a runtime check that `.then` was indeed called and log a warning or something if it wasn't

```js
const mustCallThen = fn => (...args) => {
  const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    console.warn(fn, '.then was not called')
  })

  const then = (resolve, reject) => {
    clearTimeout(timeout)
    return fn(...args).then(resolve, reject)
  }

  return { then, catch: reject => then(null, reject) }
}

async function checkPermission(permission) {
  // some async code
  return true
}

// usage example:
const yo = mustCallThen(checkPermission)
// yo is now the same function but will warn you if .then was not called right after:
yo()
// will log:
// async function checkPermission(permission) .then was not called
await yo() // wil not log
```

Comment: Your code calls setTimeout without a timeout interval, so that won't do much, but even if it had one, that interval would be wrong (no matter what number you pick) because you have no idea how long I/O, the network, a database connection, etc. is going to take to return an answer. So this solution will only work if you already know what function you're wrapping, and how long that call is allowed to wait.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans yes and no, if await is called the `.then` is called synchronously, You would be correct if you delay calling `.then` by using a step variable.

`setTimeout` without a delay will be called next event loop tick, which is enough to check if `await` was called synchronously or not.