# Is there a way to ensure await gets called on a function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Basically had an async function in JavaScript (nodejs app) that returned a list...unfortunately I forgot to call await on this `testFunction(x, y)` and so it broke some code in production. Is there a linting rule that would catch this? Is there a test I can write to ensure that this won't break because I forgot to call await (it seems like linting is the way to ensure errors like this are caught)?

```
const testFunction = async (x, y) => {
   let z = await someFunction();
  //..some code that returns a list after processing z
}
```

Comment: await will always gets called. Oh, you're looking for a lint rule. I don't see how a linter is ever going to know if a function is async or not.

Comment: What editor are you using? I would think your editor could have caught that.

Comment: Sounds more like a lack of tests problem than a linter one...

Comment: It's perfectly possible that you actually want to store the Promise in `z` instead; I don't think a linter can analyze your code this deep (speaking as a layperson with regard to linters though). Still, this is were testing comes in.

Comment: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-floating-promises/ Perhaps this could be of use? This is what I found after rabbit holing through Google.

Comment: @AdamKerik That doesn't help with OP's problem unfortunately.

Comment: It's a tricky one, even for a Linter to pick up.  Because not calling await on a Promise may indeed be something your want to do..  Think `Promise.all` etc, or even starting a new Promise to act like a fork..

Comment: You can go with TypeScript/Flow and then you'd get an error when using a Promise as if it's another type of value. Otherwise the only linter rule that can help you here is the one that mandates async functions to have an `await` but that doesn't help if you have to use `await` twice but you've only added it once. Fundamentally, this should have been caught in testing WAY before production.

Comment: @AdamKerik "TS Only".

Comment: @James - it is, this is a code base that was built with no tests, so the team is adding as we can. You can imagine why issues like this crop up.

Comment: @Nona even outside *automated* tests, you should at least manually checking if what you did was correct. Then you should have *testers*. There are three levels of tests that were skipped. Not to mention code reviews.

Comment: `/await /.test(testFunction)`

Comment: You can implement TypeScript to your project for checking return value types of everything. You can declare to function's return type and if you forget this await, linter gone mad.

Comment: This answer mentions an eslint rule called "require-await": [Check if a js function is called using await](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63765236/3113485). Docs: [ESLint Disallow async functions which have no await expression (require-await)](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/require-await), it seems to check that async functions contain at least one `await`, not exactly the same.

Comment: @terrymorse it doesn't fundamentally solve the problem of broken code going into production. This is a process failure a lot more than a tool deficiency. And what coverage ESLint can offer doesn't fix that.

Comment: @VLAZ Possibly a static type checker (JSDoc, Flow) could help. Using JSDoc, I get this warning: `let str = asyncFn() : Initializer type Promise<string> is not assignable to variable type string`.